# Best way to declare UI elements in practice

Tags: java, android

Is it better to declare an UI Element every time I need to use it inside inner class (There could be a few of them) Or can I just declare them at class level?

How will the performance differ?

Here's example code I wrote:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
    EditText et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);
    EditText et4 = findViewById(R.id.et4);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*

        Do whatever I need with UI Elements here

         */
    }
}
```

Also, is it better to declare them private?

```
private Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Comment: It is arguably better to declare them as class fields if they're to be used often, but you cannot call `findViewById()` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

natively, You can do it globally..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    }
}
```

declaring one by one and findViewById for each one is quite frustrating.. use ButterKnife instead.. clean code..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.btn1)
    protected Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should call `findViewById` method after calling `setContentView`
- And you should call `btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);` in a method .Not in a class .
- And I set `Button` and `EditText` as global variable , you can call it at other method .

Try

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn1, btn2;
    private EditText et1, et2, et3, et4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4 = findViewById(R.id.et4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just declare all the UI elements at the class level and then use `findViewById()` inside any of the methods to initialize the UI elements.

Also you cannot call `findViewById()` there. You should read about activity `lifecycle` and context to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Normally ,you should declare all UI elements at the class level, because activity hold their reference in activity lifetime.

But, if your activity needs to change it's contentView, you'd better make UI elements as local variant where they needed. this will benefit saving memories.